# Formatting ANOVA table and/or ParameterTable without using Grid?

Tags: formatting, homework

Does anyone know if there is an option or function that can automatically format the output of  `ANOVATable` and `ParameterTable`, but without using the `Grid` function ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438817/change-the-background-of-a-parameter-table-in-mathematica) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425696/customize-anova-table-in-mathematica)

Comment: Not the same...

Comment: I know it's not the same - I am giving you something to read. Plus, what is the reason behind the ban of `Grid` ?

Comment: I read that already before posting the question thanks ;-) I have an assignment at uni.. Trying to figure out maybe a new algorithm or whatever....

Answer (score 4):

You can `MapAt` `Style` to specific `Part`s:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];

lm["ANOVATable"][[1, 1]]
(*{{"","DF","SS","MS","F\[Hyphen]Statistic","P\[Hyphen]Value"},
   {x,1,7.1228,7.1228,8.7552,0.09775},
   {"Error",2,1.6271,0.81355},
   {"Total",3,8.75}} *)

rowlabels = {1, 1, 2 ;;, 1};
collabels = {1, 1, 1, 1 ;;};
content = {1, 1, 2 ;;, 2 ;;};

MapAt[Style[#, Red, 20] &, lm["ANOVATable"], {rowlabels, collabels}] (* labels *)
MapAt[Style[#, Red, 20] &, lm["ANOVATable"], {content}]  (* all content *)
MapAt[Style[#, Red, 20] &, lm["ANOVATable"], {{1, 1, 2, 5}}]  (* a specific part *)
```

[image]

Replace `"ANOVATable"` above with `"ParameterTable"` to apply styles to  `ParameterTable`.

Note that `lm["ANOVATable"][[1, 1]]` is a  ragged array; so you need to make sure that you have the right indices when styling individual pieces.

On related note, to change the `CellStyle` of the output generated by `lm["ANOVATable"]`, you can use something like

```
lm["ANOVATable"] /. "DialogStyle" -> "Subsection"
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you @kguler!